# Does an array get subsorted in the database or script?

Tags: php, mysql

I have table entry:

```
SELECT 
USER,
ROOM,
STARTDATETIME,
ENDDATETIME,
ENTRYTYPE,
ENTRYHEADING,

FROM 
ENTRY

ORDER BY DATE
```

I have this displaying using PHP where they see all of the days in the month and then on the row for the day of the month - say 1st of the month - they would see any entry with a startdatetime for the first with its row information.  Each day may have all rooms in it or whatever has an entry.  And some days have multiple entries for the same room.  It has worked pretty good.  But people want to be able to easily see where there is an empty room on a given day and its not that great for that (I do have each room color coded).

```
So I have:
1 ENTRYA
  ENTRYB
  ENTRYC
  ENTRYD
2 ENTRYE....

I want:
     ROOM-A       ROOM-B     ROOM-C    ROOM-D     ROOM-E   ROOM-F  
1    row(s)info              rowinfo
2    rowinfo
3
4
```

Is this done in the DB(mysql) or PHP?  And how would I do this for either?

Comment: It's called a pivot query and MySQL doesn't support them. You can fake it for a fixed number of fields, but the faking cannot help when your row->column transformation involves an unknown/arbitrary number of potential columns. This sort of thing is better done in client-side code, because the faked version in MySQL gets EXTREMELY ugly EXTREMELY quickly.

Comment: @MarcB - The rooms definitely aren't fixed because we have about 30 areas - with 1-15 rooms in each area and these change daily.  My PHP level is moderate.  How hard is it to get to display using PHP and what am I constructing?

Comment: not very. some like `$rooms[$row['room_name']] = $row['room_data']` - using the room name as an array key